# CGAL installation + CGAL and QT5

Tags: installation, qt5, cgal

I just installed CGAL from ubuntu 16.04 package manger and tried to run an example according to this: [http://www.cgal.org/FAQ.html#debian_demos](http://www.cgal.org/FAQ.html#debian_demos/)

after runing, the following message appeared: `NOTICE: This demo requires CGAL and Qt5, and will not be compiled.`

But the following packages are already installed:

**Package**     ,     **Installed version**

libcgal-demo    ,        4.7-4

libcgal-dev     ,  4.7-4

libcgal-ipelets  , 4.7-4

libcgal-qt5-11  ,  4.7-4

libcgal-qt5-dev  , 4.7-4

libcgal-11v5   ,   4.7-4

cmake          ,   3.5.1-1ubuntu1

cmake-data       , 3.5.1-1ubuntu1

g++             ,  4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1

I'm wondering what is the problem?

Comment: http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/installation.html#thirdpartyQt says you may need many components of Qt (Core, Gui, etc). Do you have all of them?

Answer (score 4):

Try installing the following packages: qtscript5-dev, libqt5opengl5-dev, libqt5svg5-dev or alternatively try to find demo that is not compiling and change the line in CMakeLists.txt containing

```
find_package(Qt5 QUIET COMPONENTS Xml Script OpenGL Svg)
```

into:

```
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Xml Script OpenGL Svg)
```

This will allow you to track the necessary packages (you are probably missing different packages than me).

Comment: Outstanding answer. The error reported led me straight to `$ sudo apt-get install libqt5svg5-dev`, and that removed the `NOTICE: This demo requires CGAL and Qt5, and will not be compiled.`